# How can I use the same mongodb connection throughout the app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, singleton

I'm trying this approach, but I'm not sure if that creates a new connection every time.

getMongoClient.js

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const serverURL = process.env['mongoServerURL']

module.exports = async function (){

    const mongoClient = await new MongoClient(serverURL);
    await mongoClient.connect();
    return mongoClient;
}
```

then in the app.js

```
const getMongoClient = require("./_helpers/getMongoClient.js")
module.exports = getMongoClient();
```

then in a database service.js

```
async function syncGuilds(client){

    const mongoClient = await require("../app.js")
     ... some database operations
}
module.exports = syncGuilds
```

Comment: `getMongoClient.js` creates a `MongoClient` connection, which can be used throughout the application. The method can to be called only once (in your `app.js`). The returned connection object can be passed to all other modules - as needed.

Comment: @prasad_ does that mean that I don't need to call it in app.js and then export again? instead I can use the getMongoClient.js directly in service files?

Comment: You don''t "call the app.js"- you just require that particular (only one) connection object where ever you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node modules are singleton by themselves, you don't need to worry about them. When your modules is once evaluated, it won't be evaluated again. So you will always receive same instance of the module i.e it won't create multiple instance of mongo connection.

You can check [this](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/exporting-a-single-instance-of-existing-mongodb-in-node/12368/3) and [this](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-module-import-twice/) link for more details.

Comment: So, can I use getMongoClient.js directly in service files? (without using app.js as middleman)

Comment: Yes, exactly. And keep the connection in one file and use where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

It won't create a new connection every time, If you want you can specify max connection pool size in options default value is 5. Check below link

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#connection-pool-configuration

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb");
let client = new mongodb.MongoClient(
  "url",
  {
    tls: true,
    auth: { user: "myuser", password: "mypassword" },
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    poolSize: 1,
    maxPoolSize: 1,
  }
);
```

Comment: How do I test if it is indeed the same mongoClient instance used by other files? If it is the same one, does that mean I don't have to call it in app.js and export again?